# Questions regarding DT edition in a Shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am discovering the edition functionnality of a DT object in a Shiny context. I was wondering why in the official example ([here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/)) Yihui Xie - the author - uses a dedicated function `editData()` to capture the user edition rather than simply retrieving the whole table?

In addition, why does he use a global double assignment `<<-` rather using a reactive variable and why does he show both cases `server = TRUE/FALSE` in the aforementionned demo? Is there some potential collaterals when editing a table whether `server` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` that we should be aware of?

Comment: Please do not ask several questions in a single question. With `server = TRUE`, only the visible part of the table is sent to the browser. If you edit a cell and change the page, the edit is lost; if you don't want to loose it, you have to use the proxy and `editData`. Using a reactive value instead of the super-assignment `<<-` is a possible alternative way.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Initial post split into 3 different questions.